# Detect if user is typing

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in Javascript to detect if the user is currently writing?  Writing would include focusing on any text input and on a mobile OS bringing up the keyboard.

I'm trying to determine the current "state" of the user. So normally it would be "reading", and when he's writing it should be "writing". So it is important that it goes back to "reading" once the user has finished writing.

Oh, and it has to be Javascript only, no jQuery.

Comment: Depends on which mobile OS and browser it is. For example Mobile Safari has a fully functional JavaScript engine, while Opera Mini doesn't.

Comment: for such dummy browsers you can use simple loop checking contents of input and comparing to previously catched value, to emulate onkeytyped behavior

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into `keyup` and `keydown` events. Then you could bind the key event to the `document` and when the events are fired execute your code.

More information:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Answer (score 0):

alternatively to .keydown() you could also use jquery [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) function that would trigger for every character in case the user keeps the key pressed down.

Comment: I'm trying to determine the current "state" of the user. So normally it would be "reading", and when he's writing it should be "writing". So it is important that it goes back to "reading" once the user has finished writing.

Comment: If this is the case then they would by default be "reading", if the user starts typing then you would set a flag that resets it back to "reading" after an amount of time. If the user types it resets the timer so as long as they are typing it keeps them in the "writing" state.

Comment: @Seth, yeah I think I'll do that.